# Prime factors of $a$ and $a+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

*Quick question*

> Is there any pattern to how a number's prime factors change when you increase it by $1$?
>
> Is there any way you can predict a number's prime factors based on the factors of its previous number?

Comment: No. If there is one then the twin prime conjecture and many other important problems would have been solved.

Comment: Quick answer. No, other than the obvious fact that just one of that pair is even.

Comment: Not just one of the pair is even. They share no primes whatsoever.

Comment: oh, well that's underwhelming. Do we just not know or is there genuinely no pattern to be figured out whatsoever?

Comment: When you said *iterate*, did you mean *increment*?

Comment: oh yes sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: $2399$ has only one prime factor.  $2400$ has seven.  $2401$ has four.  For the size of these numbers, the first has "few" primes and the other two have "lots".  Yet they are consecutive.

Comment: If, for example, all you know about $a$ is that its prime divisors are $2$ and $5$, then you don't know if $a+1$ is $11$, $21$, $41$, $51$, $81$, $101$, etc., etc. If, on the other hand, you know *all* the factors of $a$ (or if you know $a$'s unique factorization as a product of powers of primes), then of course you can "predict" the prime factorization of $a+1$, but you may not be able to do so efficiently.

Comment: As @Chrystomath said: we know that **all** prime divisors of $a+1$ are different from those of $a$. That's not very helpful for finding them, but certainly not zero information.

Comment: If this prediction would work , we could factor every number efficiently : We would just start with the largest prime smaller than the given number and then iteratively find the factors of all the numbers upto the desired number.

Comment: $a $ and $a+1$ are coprime

Comment: @Peter, what if the number $a$ happens to be in an unusually large gap between consecutive primes?

Comment: We know all divisors of $2^n$, yet still Fermat numbers factorization is a huge problem. Well, _not quite as huge_ as for an arbitrary number their size.

Comment: @BarryCipra In fact, my argument was not utterly rigorous. But $(1)$ the gap to the next smaller prime will be small enough even for a number with , lets say  , $2\ 000$ digits , to find it quickly. And $(2)$ , we would only need a number smaller and near the desired one that can be completely factored. We would relatively soon find such a number.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for your reply. Isn't it still only conjectured that gaps are small enough to make finding a nearby smaller prime findable in polynomial time? And do you know of any proven results that guarantee easily factored numbers (say with lots of small prime factors) if the gap is large?

Comment: @BarryCipra Rigorously, we cannot prove very much. I just wanted to point out one of the consequences if we could factor $a+1$ easily , if $a$ is completely factored. What can probably be proven is that many hard to factored numbers could be factored. this way. The proven prime gap bound would be too large, as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: "the first has "few" primes and the other two have "lots". Yet they are consecutive."  Actually my intuition tells me that because they are consecutive they will have entirely different primes and I'd expect them to have *very* different numbers of factors.  But to quantify such casual and flakey statement as "if $a$ has lots of factors $a+1$ will probably have few factors" is so casual as to b pointless. Nonetheless I do believe it to be "true".   $2^n$ will have $n+1$ factors but $2^n + 1$ can only have at the very most $\log_3 2^n + 1\approx 0.63\times n + 1$ factors for example

Comment: "If this prediction would work , we could factor every number efficiently "  That means we don't know of a way.  It doesn't mean there *isn't* a way.  Although it is very doubtful.  Predictly primes efficiently has historically been elusive and I believe most mathematicians believe it can not be solved.  But on the other hand we haven't proven it *can't* be solved either.  .... but in the end.... yes, our known results are "underwhelming"